# Ubuntu server for i.MX7D processor

Tags: server, arm

I want to install Ubuntu Server on i.MX7D processor, can someone please share details from where to download Ubuntu server image for i.MX7D processor and installation procedure.
I have found link - https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-328362 , but it has details of installing Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop version on i.MX7D.
Does Ubuntu has any roadmap planned for Ubuntu server support for i.MX7D processors ?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/server   I don't know the architecture of the processor you mention, but I'm guessing it's just an *armhf* (32bit) which is available on prior link or https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm (along with 64bit)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu usually comes with generic ARM support - it is not targeted on specific ARM embedded boards (maybe a few reference boards like the Raspberry Pi may be the exception here). That's usually where the silicon manufacturers come in - in your case Freescale/NXP.

i.MX7 is based on Cortex-A7 so you'll need an `armhf` root file system. Notice in the embedded realm the distribution is just about what's on your file system, as the Linux kernel, drivers and bootloader are usually provided by the board vendor.

That guide you pointed to is indeed about Ubuntu 14.04 but it can be used just fine as a reference with newer versions - you'll just need to get another Ubuntu filesystem archive downloaded and flashed on your SD card. And you may also want to get the latest BSP packages from NXP.

You could probably just grab the armhf rootfs from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/18.04/release/ and just replace the original `rootfs` from the BSP (I guess that would be the result of some yocto build) with the Ubuntu one while keeping the bootloader, kernel, device treees, modules ... See where that gets you.